# Counter Clicks with timer C#

Tags: c#, counter, picturebox

i am having problems making a game in C#
it goes like this: i made a picturebox bouncing with timer and then what i wanted to do was so when i click it the label would go "Points:" to "Points: 1" but it´s going like "Points:" to "Points: 162".

I think it is because interval, i can´t figure out how to resolve.

-we click the image
-points add 1
**not done yet*
-image (picturebox) desapear
-add another image (picturebox) randomly

I would like to have a point counter but with the using of timer, tha´s it.
Any help would be apreciated.

```
 int dx;
    int dy;
    int x;
    int y;
    int pts = 0;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        dx = rnd.Next(2, 5);
        dy = rnd.Next(2, 5);
        x = rnd.Next(0, this.ClientSize.Width - 1 );
        y = rnd.Next(0, this.ClientSize.Height - 1);
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(x, y);
        pictureBox1.Click += pictureBox1_Click;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        x += dx;
        if (x < 0)
        {
            dx = -dx;
        }
        else if (x + 50 > this.ClientSize.Width)
        {
            dx = -dx;
        }

        y += dy;
        if (y < 100)
        {
            dy = -dy;
        }
        else if (y + 50 > this.ClientSize.Height)
        {
            dy = -dy;
        }
        this.Invalidate();
    } 

    void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
       pts++;
       label1.Text = "Pontos: " + pts;

       pictureBox1.Location = new Point(x,y); 
    }



 this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
        this.timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
        this.pictureBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
        this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).BeginInit();
        this.panel1.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // timer1
        // 
        this.timer1.Enabled = true;
        this.timer1.Interval = 10;
        this.timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
        // 
        // pictureBox1
        // 
        this.pictureBox1.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("pictureBox1.Image")));
        this.pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(146, 243);
        this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
        this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 50);
        this.pictureBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.pictureBox1.TabStop = false;
        this.pictureBox1.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.Form1_Paint);
        // 
        // panel1
        // 
        this.panel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Teal;
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.panel1.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Arrow;
        this.panel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Top;
        this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
        this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(534, 100);
        this.panel1.TabIndex = 1;
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this.label1.AutoSize = true;
        this.label1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 26.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ButtonFace;
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(26, 27);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(144, 39);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.label1.Text = "Pontos: ";
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(534, 562);
        this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1);
        this.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Cross;
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        this.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.Form1_Paint);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).EndInit();
        this.panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.panel1.PerformLayout();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
```

ps: i am portuguese, sorry my english

Comment: You need to post the code for the Timer object

Comment: Subscribe the Click event handler only *once*.  Not over and over again with each paint, that gets the event handler to run many times.  Do it in the form constructor instead.  Also don't use Paint to move the control, set the Location property in the Tick event handler instead.  No need for a custom paint event handler anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be subscribing to the click event every time  `Form1_Paint` is called

```
 pictureBox1.Click += pictureBox1_Click;
```

Try moving it to the constructor or an initialization method..

Comment: i move that line to Form1_Load and pictureBox1.Location = new Point(x, y); to timer1_Tick and it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Code is not complete. Please specify from which even, you are firing Timer event which results in calling of "timer1_Tick" method.

Looking at question and code, I think each Timer "Click" is causing Repaint of window. Better approach would be to repaint window only on Click of Picture. Also, It seems that in the same sequence with each Time_Click, you are also calling Picture_Click (Code is not in posted code ....but as per behavior a guess) which results in increasing the Points. So, once this gets over there is probably 162 ticks and that's why you see 162 points.